# How to round all elements of a list using a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, floating-point, list-comprehension, rounding

Considering the following list of float values

```
aList = ['3.32', '1.08', '4.23']
```

How do I use a list comprehension to round it and obtain the following `[3.0, 1.0, 4.0]`?

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy just use the built function int().

```
aList = [3.32, 1.08, 4.23]
newList = []
for num in aList:
    newList.append(int(num))
print(newList)
```

**Note:** those elements in your list are not float numbers but strings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `aList` is supposed to be `['3.32', '1.08', '4.23']` (missing quote at the end).

You can convert the strings into floats, then round them with 0 digits of precision, like this:

```
newList = [round(float(n), 0) for n in aList]
```

result:

```
[3.0, 1.0, 4.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input_list = [3.32, 1.08, 4.23]
output_list = [round(x) for x in input_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `aList` that you mention

```
aList = ['3.32', '1.08', '4.23']
```

Is a list of strings, not of floats.

```
for i in aList:
    print(type(i))

[Out]: <class 'str'>
       <class 'str'>
       <class 'str'>
```

A list of floats is as follows

```
aList = [3.32, 1.08, 4.23]

for i in aList:
    print(type(i))

[Out]: <class 'float'>
       <class 'float'>
       <class 'float'>
```

Assuming that one has one of the lists above, one can use [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round), [`float()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) (this will return a floating point number from a number or a string - so it would work for both of the cases above), and a list comprehension, as follows

```
round_0 = [round(float(number), 0) for number in aList]

[Out]: [3.0, 1.0, 4.0]
```

For a list of floats, one can also do the following as well

```
aList = [3.32, 1.08, 4.23]

round_0 = [round(number, 0) for number in aList]
```

---

**Alternative cases that may be relevant**

If one wants to round to the decimal point

```
round_1 = [round(float(number), 1) for number in aList]

[Out]: [3.3, 1.1, 4.2]
```

Assuming one only wants `[3, 1, 4]`, the following will do the work

```
round0 = [round(float(number)) for number in aList]

[Out]: [3, 1, 4]
```

If one has a list with big numbers and wants to round on the left of the decimal point, the following will do the work

```
testlist = [98789.55, 38597.89, 65874.58]

round_2 = [round(float(number), -2) for number in testlist]

[Out]: [98800.0, 38600.0, 65900.0]
```